# Pure Python dictionary to lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary with the following structure (number of keys is not determined):

```py
dico = { 2017 : [a,b,c,d....], 2018: [1,2,3,4,5,6...] }
```

The output I want is the following:

```
2017 , 2018 
 a   ,  1
 b   ,  2
 c   ,  3
 d   ,  3
 e   ,  4
```

Is there a builtin function or something? I want to do it in pure python (no pandas at least).

I can use zip:

```py
for v in zip(*dico.values()):
   print(v)
```

The output I get is:

```
('a', '1')
('b', '2')
('c', '3')
('d', '4')
('e', '5')
('f', '6')
```

Almost ! In fact what I want is to print each item of a list side by side (according to their index)

I have also tried that, but not very elegant:

```
for v in zip(*dico.values()):
    temp = ""
    for vv in v:
        temp += vv +','
    print(temp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have combined all of our solutions , it tooks 2.5 s to execute on large dictionary (24 keys * 34000 entries), it looks like the more "pythonic" way to write it:

```
time1= time.time()
print(','.join(list(dico.keys())))
for v in zip(*dico.values()):
    print(','.join(map(str, v)))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of values in `v` you can do like this:

```
for v in zip(*dico.values()):
   print(*v)
```

The `*v` syntax will unpack the list/tuple for you.

Comment: Good idea, it's working, but I do not have the ',' ; And it's way to long on my real large dictionnary (24 keys with value of 34 000 entries lists) --> 56 seconds VS 2 second with my method.

Answer (score 2):

you could try this with formatted strings and your solution with zip:

```
dico = { 2017 : ['a','b','c','d'], 2018: [1,2,3,4,5,6] }

print(' , '.join(map(str,dico.keys())))
for x,y in zip(*dico.values()):
   print('{0: <5},{1:5}'.format(x,y) )
```

Output:

```
2017 , 2018
a    ,    1
b    ,    2
c    ,    3
d    ,    4
```

**Edit**:
Since in the answer you posted, the width and the alignment the columns are not taking into account, only there are  joined by a `','` you could try this:

```
dico = { 2017 : ['a','b','c','d'], 2018: [1,2,3,4,5,6],2019: [1,2,3,4,5,6],2020: [1,2,3,4,5,6] }

keys=','.join(map(str,dico.keys()))
print(keys)

for v in zip(*dico.values()):  
    print(*v, sep = ",")
```

Output:

```
2017,2018,2019,2020
a,1,1,1
b,2,2,2
c,3,3,3
d,4,4,4
```

Comment: Thank you @MrNobody33, I have edited my original post, in fact I have more than 2 keys to unpack.

Comment: Ok, all your values are of length 1, and all your keys are of length 4? @Pdeuxa

Comment: The value of a key is a list. These lists have also an undefined lenght (but still the same len for all keys value). I have just posted an answer, which seems to do the job well in a few line of code.

Comment: Actually, that answer you posted will give you error, because you have to map the keys to string, since they are ints.

Comment: I didn't know that the width of the columns doesn't cares, because, the answer you posted, only separates the values with a ',', so, in that case see the last edit of my answer, I think it could be more pythonic.

Comment: Good, I timed the two methods, and the one I posted is faster (agreed for the string mapping on the keys). I guess printing (*v) adds another hidden "for loop", as it as to iterate on each values of 'v'.

Comment: Oh okay, so, glad you find your answer :). Also, try to be more specific, because, maybe the width and the alignment of the columns of the desired output, could give wrong specifications, at least for me, at first I thought about join, but I ruled it out, because it will not consider the above things ( width,...). Just a suggestion.

Comment: Yes, sorry I tried to simplify my issue for a better understanding, and thus loosing it's complexity. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just print the elements instead. Try:

```py
for v in zip(*dico.values()):
   for element in v:
       print(element, end = " ")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in fact my dictionnary will have a large number of key (+100) , I can not write it by hand.

Comment: You can loop while printing I think. I edited the answer with loops.

Comment: I had the same idea, I do not know if there is a more efficient way, but thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
for v in zip(*dico.values()):
   val, idx = v
   print(f'{idx}, {val}')
```